# eshell: Is there a built-in mechanism to permit an alias to process the ARGS?

Tags: eshell

I would like to set up a few straight *alias* (without fixed ARGS) for some external executables in Eshell that need access to the command-line ARGS (that will vary).  The function `eshell-maybe-replace-by-alias` is expressly designed to *omit* the ARGS.

**EXAMPLE**:  The `alias` file within the Eshell folder [`eshell-aliases-file`] contains the following entries below.  When I call `git diff SHA1234567890 > patch.diff`, `eshell-maybe-replace-by-alias` *excludes* `diff SHA1234567890` and the patch file that gets created is a printout from `git` telling me what types of command line options are possible -- this is because `git` was called by Eshell without any arguments.

```
alias git /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/bin/git
alias curl /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/bin/curl
```

I hacked the last line of `eshell-maybe-replace-by-alias` to include the ARGS [i.e., `,(eshell-parse-command (nth 1 alias) args)`], but have a feeling that there may be an existing method to better handle this dilemma.

I played around with creating a custom function named eshell/COMMAND, but ran into several problems with with pre/post command hooks needing to be suppressed the first loop; an extra `\n` that needed to be suppressed the second loop; escaping double-quotes (of strings greater than one word) in order to survive the first loop; and, an unresolved issue when dealing with redirection `>`.  Therefore, the hack of `eshell-maybe-replace-by-alias` seems the easiest approach so far.

[I feel as though a bug report is not the right avenue at this point because Emacs 26 expressly has the ARGS labeled as `_args`; i.e., disregard the ARGS.]

Comment: I don't know much about eshell so I'm not the person to help here, but FWIW I found the question a bit confusing, and suspect that some concrete examples would clarify both the problem, and what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @phils -- thank you for the constructive help.  I added a specific example to the question above.

Comment: If you want to pass arguments to the alias, its definition needs to end in '$*' (the eshell info manual is short but pretty clear)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to @rpluim's comment and [(eshell) Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Aliases.html):

> Note that unlike aliases in Bash, arguments must be handled
>   explicitly.

Here is the way to create an alias to `git`:

```
$ alias git '/usr/local/bin/git $*'
```

The above Eshell command will write the following to `eshell-aliases-file`:

```
alias git /usr/local/bin/git $*
```

BTW, as you can see Eshell command line and `eshell-aliases-file` don't use the exactly same syntax (i.e, the quote), and the difference does matter according to my test. This is weird,